# How can I geotag images with locations in a CSV file?

Tags: geotagging

A similar question has been asked, but I'm probably typing it wrong while writing the code.

I have folders of .JPG images that I need to geotag. and I have csv file. How can I geotag these images?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Photo.SE! If you already have chosen a tool to geotag the images (I assume so as you say "*while writing the code*") this is more of a programming question and should be better asked at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure to include your code in the question and indicate what is not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I geotag images with location data in a CSV file?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/61490/how-can-i-geotag-images-with-location-data-in-a-csv-file)

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke, the OP post there "answer" (same as question above)

Comment: I see... Then I think this reinforces my first comment: the issue is not with photography, but with proper use of a command line tool (which by chance is related to images). I would be fine with leaving this question open if the OP would [edit] it to include what is actually failing in their code, because the answer to "How can I geotag these images" is in the linked post.

Comment: If you format your CSV into a .gpx file you can use Lightroom to autotag the images.  I don't know if Lightroom accepts CSV

Comment: Thanks a lot for answers. I tried this and it worked. . I have also "heading" information in the excel. And i want to see also "heading" information on the attribute table when i import images in qgis.